# Iteration within Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way **within a B2C custom policy** to perform an iteration on some Json returned from a REST call.

Example:

If the REST service returned:

```
[
    {
          name: "item1",
          value: "value1"
    },
    {
          name: "item2",
          value: "value2"
    },
    {
          name: "item3",
          value: "value3"
    }
]
```

I want to be able to iterate through this array, and perform a calculation, and set a claim boolean if a record is found.

`calculation(name, value) == calculation(another_input_claim, value)`

I cannot use another REST service, as the specifics of the calculation need to be securely performed inside the B2C policy.

I can change the Json format of the input array if this helps?

Do you have any suggestions on implementing this within a B2C policy?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options available here in B2C which I feel can be used is "[GetClaimsFromJsonArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimsfromjsonarray)" This does help in extracting the values from the JSON Array.